# How to delete a record in Django models?

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models, django-queryset

I want to delete a particular record like:

```
delete from table_name where id = 1;
```

How can I do this in a django model?

Comment: Agreed with @Freedom_Ben, but for future readers that like the f* manual anyway, this is what you're looking for: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#topics-db-queries-delete

Answer (score 831):

There are a couple of ways:

To delete it directly:

```
SomeModel.objects.filter(id=id).delete()
```

To delete it from an instance:

```
instance = SomeModel.objects.get(id=id)
instance.delete()
```

Comment: Note that the first one will not call the .delete() method of the object, so if you have 'cleanup' code in that method it will not be called. Generally not an issue, but worth keeping in mind.

Comment: @Matthew Schinckel: that is true. If you want to have a custom delete method than you should be using the `pre_delete` or `post_delete` signal instead.

Comment: I dont know what is the case after DJango 1.4, but this is actually fetching all the PKs and then delete by those PKs. So eg if you delete by an arbitrary field, this can be way slower then the SQL counterpart... :(

Comment: @VajkHermecz: that is true and the expected behaviour because of the delete signals. The Django signals system has to track all database changes because something could hook to it (like reversion does).

Comment: Could you use this? `SomeModel.objects.get(id=id).delete()`

Comment: @CyberJacob: yes, delete works on both models and querysets

Comment: Note that delete does not work on the base model object (it's the only model method that doesn't) as a deliberate move to reduce accidental deletion. If you want to delete everything you'll need to use the "all()" filter like this: SomeModel.objects.all().delete()

Comment: worth noting: the first option which uses the filter returns a queryset. this means that if you do not filter by primary key you will delete multiple records. i realize the question was asking particularly about the id but still worth putting this out there as a friendly reminder.

Comment: You can use the return value of `delete()` to check what you were deleting.
It returns a tuple with the count of deleted objects and a dictionary with details about the deleted types, e.g.
`(1, {'yourapp.SomeModel': 1})`.

Comment: Just for my understanding : do we need to call the save() method after deleting?

Comment: Saving is for inserting and updating records so you don't want that while deleting.

Comment: how to delete 2+ entries? like `id in 1,2,3,4,5,6`

Comment: @Toskan pretty much exactly like that: `SomeModel.objects.filter(id__in=[ 1,2,3,4,5,6]).delete()`

Answer (score 88):

```
MyModel.objects.get(pk=1).delete()
```

this will raise exception if the object with specified primary key doesn't exist because at first it tries to retrieve the specified object.

```
MyModel.objects.filter(pk=1).delete()
```

this wont raise exception if the object with specified primary key doesn't exist and it directly produces the query

```
DELETE FROM my_models where id=1
```

Comment: You have used `pk`, @Wolph used `id`. What is the difference?

Comment: With `pk` you are filtering using the table primary key. I think @Milad assumed that since @Wolf was using `id` he was searching on the primary key. Generally this could be wrong if you set a different field as primary key in your model

Comment: @Gathide You can see in django https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/that ```id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)``` Therefore, if you have not changed the defualt primary key of your model, both ***id*** or ***pk*** work because ***pk** refers to primary key.

Answer (score 32):

if you want to delete one instance then write the code

```
entry = Account.objects.get(id=5)
entry.delete()
```

if you want to delete all instance then write the code

```
entries = Account.objects.all()
entries.delete()
```

Answer (score 19):

If you want to delete one item

```
wishlist = Wishlist.objects.get(id = 20)
wishlist.delete()
```

If you want to delete all items in Wishlist for example

```
Wishlist.objects.all().delete()
```

Answer (score 10):

Extending the answer by [wolph](https://stackoverflow.com/users/54017/wolph)

Note that you should pass request as a parameter to your delete function in your views. An example would be like:

```py
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def delete(request, id):
    YourModelName.objects.filter(id=id).delete()

    return redirect('url_name')
```

Comment: Which is 'the top voted comment'? It is better is you reference it, e.g. by its author, as it may not remain 'top' forever.

Answer (score 9):

The `delete()` method is used to delete model instances from a database.This method immediately deletes the object. this method returns the number of object deleted.

Example:

For deleting one record:

```py
data_to_be_deleted = Modelname.objects.get(fieldname = value)
data_to_be_deleted.delete()
```

As get method returns a single object from queryset only single record will be deleted.If value supplied doesn't exist this will throw an error.If there are multilpe records in table for same value then also it will throw an error so good practice is to use a single unique value while using get.

For deleting multiple record according to a condition:

For condition based deletion filter method is used on queryset and then delete is called.

```py
data_to_be_deleted = Modelname.objects.filter(fieldname = value)
data_to_be_deleted.delete()
```

For deleting all records:

For deletion of all model instances/records from database table you need to call delete method on all

```py
data_to_be_deleted = Modelname.objects.all()
data_to_be_deleted.delete()
```

Note: code can be written in single line as `Modelname.objects.all().delete()`, but for clear understanding, I have used multiple lines.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use [`get_object_or_404()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404), rather than directly using [`get()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.get) as while using get() we explicitly raise the error of 404.

But, while using `get_object_or_404` it is automatically done.

> `get_object_or_404` According to 4.0 docs, Calls get() on a given model manager, but it raises Http404 instead of the model’s DoesNotExist exception.

Use it like:

For bulk deletion:

```py
AnyModel.objects.filter(id=id).delete()
```

For deleting single instance, use `get_object_or_404()` instead of `get()` in the following way:

```py
instance=get_object_or_404(anyModel,id=id)
instance.delete()
```

If, not found raises 404 automatically.

Answer (score 2):

It is as simple as calling the following.

```py
SomeModel.objects.get(pk=1).delete()
# Or
SomeModel.objects.filter(pk=1).delete()

# SQL equivalent
# delete from table_name where id = 1;
```

In case you want to remove multiple records based on id,
use the `__in` query [lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#field-lookups)

```py
SomeModel.objects.fitler(pk__in=[1,2,3,4,5,...]).delete()

# SQL equivalent
# delete from table_name where id in (1,2,4,5,...);
```

In case you want to delete all records, use `.all()` to retrieve all queries,
then `.delete()`.

```py
SomeModel.objects.all().delete()

# SQL equivalent
# delete from table_name;
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I do it:

```
instance = SomeModel.objects.get(id=1)

instance.delete()
```

For me it looks easy to understand, that's why I use this approach.

Answer (score 0):

you can delete the objects directly from the admin panel or else there is also an option to delete specific or selected id from an interactive shell by typing in python3 manage.py shell (python3 in Linux).
If you want the user to delete the objects through the browser (with provided visual interface) e.g. of an employee whose ID is 6 from the database, we can achieve this with the following code,
emp = employee.objects.get(id=6).delete()

THIS WILL DELETE THE EMPLOYEE WITH THE ID is 6.

If you wish to delete the all of the employees exist in the DB instead of get(), specify all() as follows:
employee.objects.all().delete()