# delete() function not working

Tags: python, django

delete() function not working in django,

```
def delete_hardware (request):
    notice = ''
    inventory = get_object_or_404(inventory, id = request.GET.get('id'))
    if inventory:
        inventory.delete()
        notice = "Hardware was deleted"
    return render_to_response('form.html', {'notice': notice},
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

......and these are my codes in form.html

```
<td bgcolor='#f1f1f1'><a onclick="javascript:confirmDelete('/delete/?id={{id}}')">
<img src='{{ MEDIA_URL }}/images/delete.png' width=25 height=25 />
            </a></td>
```

Comment: There is a question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3805958/how-to-delete-a-record-in-django-models) that tries this topic, maybe that can help you.

Comment: what about the script for confirmDelete?

Comment: Ok I will just provide a sample code

Comment: function confirmDelete(delUrl) {
   if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete hardware from inventory?")) {
  parent.TINY.box.hide();
      document.location = delUrl;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**views.py**

```
def delete_hardware (request, id):
    inventory = get_object_or_404(inventory, pk=id).delete()
    messages.success(request, "Hardware was deleted!")
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('app_name:url_name'))
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^delete/(?P<id>\d+)/$', 'delete_hardware', 
    name='delete_hardware'),
```

I can't provide a full detail codes because your not putting your complete codes in your question. I don't know why but it's up to you. This is only a guide and I hope it will clear your mind. You can only get the data if your form has submit the method=GET

```
<a href="/delete/{{value.id}}" class="delete-hardware">Delete</a>

<script>
$('.delete-hardware').click(function(){
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    document.location.href = url;
});
</script>
```

Comment: Can you please provide codes for your template because your views has no problem

Comment: Just update your question, don't put it here. People who read that codes won't understand it easily :)

Answer (score 0):

it should be `request.GET['id']`

Just try

```
def delete_hardware (request):
 notice = " "
 id = request.GET['id']
 try:
   inv = inventory.objects.get(id = id)
   inv.delete()
   notice = "Hardware was deleted"
 except inventory.DoesNotExist:
    raise Http404
 return render_to_response('form.html', {'notice': notice},
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: inventory = get_object_or_404(inventory, id = request.GET['id'])

--> It doesn't work :(

Comment: is it giving you an error? or just not working? –not working :(

Comment: @Jonathan If `request.GET` is a dict, it doesn't matter if you use the `[key]` or `.get(key)` syntax

Comment: `request.GET` is an instance of a `QueryDict` object which implements standard dictionary methods -- including `.get()`. From the doc, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.get  *Uses the same logic as __getitem__() above, with a hook for returning a default value if the key doesn't exist.*

Comment: nothing, it just not working.. it doesn't delete the values in my inventory.

Comment: @ChamYuiCanonizado what happens if you simply hard code the `id` to, say, `1`, and delete it?  `inv = inventory.objects.get(id=1);
   inv.delete()`