# How can i delete a database row from a Django view?

Tags: python, django

I created a form where an user can delete some preferences from the Database.
Here is my view:

```
if 'button2' in request.POST:
    instance = Keys.objects.get(id=request.POST['id']) 
    form2 = DeleteKey(request.POST, instance=instance)
    if form2.is_valid():
        profile = form.save(commit=False)
        profile.key = ''
        profile.save()

        messages.success(request, f"Success")
        return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path_info)
```

And the form:

```
class DeleteKey(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Keys
        fields = ()

    def save(self, commit=True):
        send = super(DeleteKey, self).save(commit=False)

        if commit:
            send.save()
        return send
```

This code **works**, the problem is that i'm not really deleting the row from my own database, i'm just setting that field to an empty string. Is there any way to completely delete the row, instead? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please fix the 3rd line in your view ```form2 = form=...``` this is clearly a typo

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete a record in Django models?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3805958/how-to-delete-a-record-in-django-models)

Comment: My bad for not making more research; yes the question was already answered, ineed. And yes, it was a typo @tomgalpin. Thank you!