# How can i delete item in django?

Tags: python, django

So can someone help me how can i delete the item in tech with tim django todo app project? I really need this one to understand how delete works and models in django. [This is the source code for tech with tim django todo app](https://github.com/techwithtim/Django-Website.git)

Comment: Which item you need to delete ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete a record in Django models?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3805958/how-to-delete-a-record-in-django-models)

Answer (score 1):

use below reference

```
YourModel.objects.filter(id=id).delete()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the steps outlined here: [How to delete a record in Django models?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3805958/how-to-delete-a-record-in-django-models)

Namely,

```
ModelName.objects.filter(id=id).delete()
```