# How to delete entry in django?

Tags: python, django

there is a small django project that has methods for creating a topic, creating and editing posts within it.

I don't understand how to write a method to delete a post in a topic

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .models import Topic, Entry
from .forms import TopicForm, EntryForm
from django.http import Http404




@login_required()
def new_entry(request, topic_id):
    topic = Topic.objects.get(id=topic_id)
    check_topic_owner(topic.owner, request)
    if request.method != "POST":
        form = EntryForm()
    else:
        form = EntryForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_entry = form.save(commit=False)
            new_entry.topic = topic
            new_entry.save()
            return redirect('composetopic:topic', topic_id=topic_id)

    context = {'topic': topic, 'form': form}
    return render(request, 'composetopic/new_entry.html', context)


@login_required()
def edit_entry(request, entry_id):
    entry = Entry.objects.get(id=entry_id)
    topic = entry.topic
    check_topic_owner(topic.owner, request)

    if request.method != "POST":
        form = EntryForm(instance=entry)
    else:
        form = EntryForm(instance=entry, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('composetopic:topic', topic_id=topic.id)

    context = {'entry': entry, 'topic': topic, 'form': form}
    return render(request, 'composetopic/edit_entry.html', context)


def check_topic_owner(owner, request):
    if owner != request.user:
        raise Http404
```

i was tried to add delete_entry() function, but its not working

Comment: This question is already answered, check this url: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51534562/13992590

Answer (score 0):

```py
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .models import Topic, Entry
from .forms import TopicForm, EntryForm
from django.http import Http404

@login_required()
def delete_entry(request, topic_id):
    try:
        topic = Topic.objects.get(id=topic_id) 
        topic.delete()
    except Topic.DoesNotExist as e:
        topic = None

    if request.method != "POST":
        form = EntryForm()
    else:
        form = EntryForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_entry = form.save(commit=False)
            new_entry.topic = topic # <Topic: Topic object (None)> topic or None
            return redirect('composetopic:topic', topic_id=topic_id) # deleted id

    context = {'topic': topic, 'form': form} # <Topic: Topic object (None)> topic or None
    return render(request, 'composetopic/deleted_entry.html', context)
```

topic should return a null queryset instance if has beed deleted correctly (id exist and object is validated) if is not is just set to `None`

```
from app.models import Topic
>>> Topic.objects.all()
<QuerySet [. . .]>
#...
>>> topic = Topic.objects.get(id = id)
>>> topic.delete()
<Topic: Topic object (None)> # You can still access to his attributes but this not exist in database
```

if id object is not valid, raise an error `self.model.DoesNotExists` then a `try-except` statement is used when you call `get` method, also when you check for type of request ("POST", "GET") you need to modify how and where redirect deleted objects or something like render a page with text 'deleted topic' and some information about deleted object.